# filtering lines based on the presence of 2 short sequences in python

Tags: python

I have a text file like this example:

example:

```
>chr9:128683-128744
GGATTTCTTCTTAGTTTGGATCCATTGCTGGTGAGCTAGTGGGATTTTTTGGGGGGTGTTA
>chr16:134222-134283
AGCTGGAAGCAGCGTGAATAAAACAGAATGGCCGGGACCTTAAAGGCTTTGCTTGGCCTGG
>chr16:134226-134287
GGAAGCAGCGTGGGAATCACAGAATGGACGGCCGATTAAAGGCTTTGCTTGGCCTGGATTT
>chr1:134723-134784
AAGTGATTCACCCTGCCTTTCCGACCTTCCCCAGAACAGAACACGTTGATCGTGGGCGATA
>chr16:135770-135831
GCCTGAGCAAAGGGCCTGCCCAGACAAGATTTTTTAATTGTTTAAAAACCGAATAAATGTT
```

this file is divided into different parts and every part has 2 rows. the 1st row starts with `>` (and this row is called ID) and the 2nd row is the sequence of letters.
I want to search for 2 short motif (`AATAAA` and `GGAC`) in the sequence of letters and if they contain these motifs, I want to get the the ID and sequence of that part. 
but the point is `AATAAA` should be the 1st sequence and `GGAC` will come after that. there is a distance between them but this distance can be 2 letters or more.

expected output:

```
>chr16:134222-134283
AGCTGGAAGCAGCGTGAATAAAACAGAATGGCCGGGACCTTAAAGGCTTTGCTTGGCCTGG
```

I am trying to do that in python using the following command:

```
infile = open('infile.txt', 'r')
mot1 = 'AATAAA'
mot2 = 'GGAC'
new = []
for line in range(len(infile)):
    if not infile[line].startswith('>'):
        for match in pattern.finder(mot1) and pattern.finder(mot2):
            new.append(infile[line-1])


with open('outfile.txt', "w") as f:
    for item in new:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

this code does not return what I want. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: `grep -B 1 'AATAAA.*GGAC'`

Comment: what is `pattern.finder`?? I mean, did you use a certain module.. or this is a pre-defined class??

Answer (score 0):

You can group the ID with sequence, and then utilize `re.findall`:

```
import re
data = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')]
new_data = [[data[i], data[i+1]] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)]
final_result = [[a, b] for a, b in new_data if re.findall('AATAAA\w{2,}GGAC', b)]
```

Output:

```
[['>chr16:134222-134283', 'AGCTGGAAGCAGCGTGAATAAAACAGAATGGCCGGGACCTTAAAGGCTTTGCTTGGCCTGG']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've got your idea about `this distance can be 2 letters or more`, and is it obligatory to check, but following code gives you desired output:

```
mot1 = 'AATAAA'
mot2 = 'GGAC'

with open('infile.txt', 'r') as inp:
    last_id = None
    for line in inp:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            last_id = line
        else:
            if mot1 in line and mot2 in line:
                print(last_id)
                print(line)
```

You can redirect output to a file if you want

Comment: how can I export it into a file?

Comment: `python myapp.py > file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex and a dictionary comprehension:

```
import re

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    data = dict(zip(lines[::2],lines[1::2]))

{k.strip(): v.strip() for k,v in data.items() if re.findall(r'AATAAA\w{2,}GGAC', v)}
```

Returns:

```
{'>chr16:134222-134283': 'AGCTGGAAGCAGCGTGAATAAAACAGAATGGCCGGGACCTTAAAGGCTTTGCTTGGCCTGG'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may slice the irrelevant part of the string if `mot1` is found in it. Here's a way to do it:

```
from math import ceil

infile = open('infile.txt', 'r')
text = infile.readlines()
infile.close()

mot1 = 'AATAAA'
mot2 = 'GGAC'

check = [(text[x], text[x+1]) for x in range(ceil(len(text)/2))]

result = [(x + '\n' + y) for (x, y) in check if mot1 in y and mot2 in y[(y.find(mot1)+len(mot1)+2):]]

with open('outfile.txt', "w") as f:
    for item in result:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not too big, you can read it at once, and use re.findall():

```
    import re
    with open("infile.txt") as finp:
        data=finp.read()
    with open('outfile.txt', "w") as f:
        for item in re.findall(r">.+?[\r\n\f][AGTC]*?AATAAA[AGTC]{2,}GGAC[AGTC]*", data):
            f.write(item+"\n")

"""
+? and *?       means non-greedy process;
>.+?[\r\n\f]    matches a line starting with '>' and followed by any characters to the end of the line; 
[AGTC]*?AATAAA  matches any number of A,G,T,C characters, followed by the AATAAA pattern; 
[AGTC]{2,}      matches at least two or more characters of A,G,T,C;
GGAC            matches the GGAC pattern;
[AGTC]*         matches the empty string or any number of A,G,T,C characters.
"""
```